# I don't understand this notation - economic formulas for compound interst factors and the like

Tags: notation

I don't understand this notation at all, but it's what my text book primarily uses.

Example:
[image: textbook example]

How does $(A/G,i,n)=1.427$ ?

Is the "A/G" part basically like and identifier, and that tells you what equation you have to look-up to solve the problem?

i.e.: I found this definition for $(A/G,i,n)$ in an earlier section of the book.  I suppose I'm just failing to see where to go from here.
[image: definition for the example]

FWIW, I've been solving these problems using a different method that was also explained in this chapter.  I basically just find the present value ($PV$) by treating the cash-flow diagram like a moment diagram and then I can derive the uniform payment from the $PV$.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "weird notation" that you don't understand ? If you put $i = 6 \%$ $ = 0.06$ and $n = 4$ in the last equality, you get the answer $1.427$, so I don't understand what you expect. Could you clarify or show what you have done please ?

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Why ? Using MathJax is fine with me to be sure, but is it worth it learning LaTeX just to post a (rather elementary) question on math.stackexchange ? I fear it might be a deterrent for some people...

Comment: Why? See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.

Comment: @DietrichBurde - I posted a screenshot to include the cashflow diagrams. I wasn't sure if those were relevant to helping understand the question.   I generally try to use MathJax/LaTex for questions on this site, I just didn't know if the cashflow diagrams were relevant and didn't know how to capture those in MathJax.

Comment: @lmsteffan - you actually answered my question with your comment. I don't know why that was so opaque to me.  I guess I was thrown off by the A/G, but I'm guessing that's just like the "identifier" for the equation you're supposed to use?  The book never really explains how to interpret this notation and I've never seen it before, so I suppose I was just getting tripped up by it. It seems I had all the pieces, I just wasn't seeing how they fit together until you suggest I could go back and plug in the values from the notation to solve either side of the original inequality.  Makes sense now!

Comment: @lmsteffan - I realized I was using an alternate method from the book to solve these, so I'll go back and edit my question to clarify. That's probably part of the issue I was having. They show multiple ways to solve the problem (which is good) but I think that was kind of tripping me up since I picked up one method earlier and it was easy/intuitive for me, so I just kept using that method and I think that was hampering my ability to understand this other definition...